# How to check if FORM Realm authentication failed?

Tags: tomcat, authentication

I use FORM Authentication.

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
       <form-login-page>/loginPage.jsp</form-login-page>
       <form-error-page>/loginPage.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>                
</login-config>
```

I would like to use the same JSP for my form-login-page and form-error-page, for sake of code reuse. I use a Realm ( *org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm*  ).

In my JSP, I would like to display error messages if the authentication failed. 
Does Realm store anything in the request, which I could check?

Answer (score 1):

Add a parameter to the url for the error page:

```
<form-login-config>
    <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
    <form-error-page>/login.jsp?error=true</form-error-page>
</form-login-config>
```

In your login.jsp, check whether an error occurred and display an error message if it did:

```
<c:if test="${not empty error}">
    <p class="error">Login failed. Please try again.</p>
</c:if>
```

This form does not let you output any specific reason why the login failed. However, security considerations already make it a bad practice to do so, so that should not be a problem. E.G. You should not *want* to output detailed messages like "No user registered by that name." or "Wrong password for user X.", because that would help an attacker to break in to the system.

Just tell them that login failed. Easy and good security practice, what more do you want?  :)

Comment: Is there a work around to pass arguments to error page (dynamically, provided by the class that realizes the authentication described in login-config)? I want to show to the user if his user is blocked or no, and/or his username/password is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this by having the error page re-direct to the login-page via http headers and by having the error-page include javascript to open the login in an iframe below the error.

Comment: Thanks, it looks too complicated. There must be an easiest way